# Merge yml files for Cloucustodian policies

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm using Cloudcustodian as a Cloud compliance tool.

For best-practice usage, I'd like to separate my policies, and merge them together in a pipeline when deploying said policies.

Let's say I have 2 policy file: `shutdown.yml` and `logs.yml`. Putting only example content, not actual Cloucustodian policies.

shutdown.yml:

```
policies:

  - name: start-ec2-office-hours
    resource: ec2
```

logs.yml:

```
policies:

  - name: logs-retention-period
    resource: log-group
```

How could I merge those file to have at the end

```
policies:

  - name: start-ec2-cologne-office-hours
    resource: ec2

  - name: logs-retention-period
    resource: log-group
```

?

Of course I tried things like

```
cat *.yml > test.yml
```

But I end up with `policies` being duplicated, which is an issue.

Is there any way to perform that using `yq` or other (light) tools?

EDIT -
It seems that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72968116/3794110) from Inian mostly do the trick.

What I actually have is `.yml.j2` file like

logs.yml.j2

```
policies

  - name: cloudwatch-set-log-group-retention
    resource: log-group
    actions:
      - type: retention
        days: {{ CWLogGroupRetentionPeriod.dev }}
        days: 7
```

shutdown.yml.j2

```
policies:

  - name: start-ec2office-hours
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - type: onhour
        weekends: {{ OfficeHours.weekends }}
        tag: Schedule
        default_tz: cet
        onhour: {{ OfficeHours.hour_start }}
```

Which gives me some weird `days: {? {CWLogGroupRetentionPeriod.dev: ''} : ''}`:

`$> yq ea '. as $item ireduce({}; . *+ $item)' *.yml.j2`

```
policies:

  - name: cloudwatch-set-log-group-retention
    resource: log-group
    actions:
      - type: retention
        days: {? {CWLogGroupRetentionPeriod.dev: ''} : ''}
        days: 7
  - name: start-ec2-office-hours
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - type: onhour
        weekends: {? {OfficeHours.weekends: ''} : ''}
        tag: Schedule
```

Answer (score 1):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), i.e. the Go implementation of `yq` the task is pretty straight forward. It has operators to merge objects from multiple files, [Merging all files](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merging-all-files) and using the [append arrays option](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-appending-arrays)

```bash
yq ea '. as $item ireduce({}; . *+ $item)' shutdown.yml logs.yml
```

As tested on version 4.25.3

Comment: Is there any way to deal with .yml.j2? See updated answer.

Comment: @Mornor Unfortunately, the template files (Jinja) are not valid YAML files, until they are rendered. yq tool uses the go-yaml parser underneath. My best guess would be that the template files won't be supported by the tool

Comment: That's what I thought indeed. Thanks for the help nonetheless! Will continue looking for a solution and post an update here if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's an alternative using the other yq tool [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y '.policies += input.policies' shutdown.yml logs.yml
```

```yaml
policies:
  - name: start-ec2-office-hours
    resource: ec2
  - name: logs-retention-period
    resource: log-group
```

Tested on version yq 3.0.2